# Reversing the axis range in 3D graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to python , so help me to overcome this problem.

I have plotted a 3D graph using some random points.
After plotting i got a graph
But to get the desired graph , i need to reverse the Y axis.
I did it using

```
gg.scatter(Ys1,Xs1,Zs1)

gg = plt.gca()

del Ys1[:],Xs1[:],Zs1[:]

gg.set_xlabel(' Y Label')
gg.set_ylabel(' X Label')
gg.set_zlabel(' Z Label')

plt.gca()invert_yaxis()
```

My graph is reversed but unfortunately am not getting the axis range displayed in my plot.
If i don reverse , am getting them displayed.

How do i get my axis range displayed.

Sorry am not able to post my graphs since don't have reputation above 10.

I'll be glad if this is solved.
Thank you.

Comment: The code you included won't execute due to a syntax error, I can guess what you're doing, but you might try copying and pasting the actual code you're using.

Comment: @Ram Please include _all_ your code, not just bits and pieces! This makes it easier for others to copy-paste you code and solve the problem.

Comment: Also, assuming the code you have run _before_ this snippet is correct, and you change your last line to `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` (include the missing `.`), this seems to work on Python 2.7.5, numpy 1.7.1 and matplotlib 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

Ram please consider the comments made above as they will help you get better responses. I have attempted to interpret your code and give a working solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create data so anyone can run the script
n = 1000

Xs1 = np.random.randint(0,3,n)
Ys1 = np.linspace(0,10,n)
Zs1 = np.exp(Ys1)


# This needs to be BEFORE gg.scatter otherwise it is nonsense
gg = plt.gca(projection="3d")

# This is how I would invert a list
Ys1_inverted = [Ys1[n-1-i] for i in range(n)]

# One can plot either Ys1 or Ys1 inverted here (see images below)
gg.scatter(Xs1,Ys1,Zs1)

gg.set_xlabel(' Y Label')
gg.set_ylabel(' X Label')
gg.set_zlabel(' Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Using the two different lists `Ys1` and `Ys1_inverted` in the `plot` command gives the following images:

[image: Using Ys1 data]

`Ys1_inverted`
[image: Using Ys1_inverted data]

This method displays the correct ranges for all axis.